# Organizing results of experiments with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following input data. Each line is the result of one experiment:

```
  instance algo  profit  time
        x    A      10   0.5
        y    A      20   0.1
        z    A      13   0.7
        x    B      39   0.9
        y    B      12   1.2
        z    B      14   0.6
```

And I would like to generate the following table:

```
            A               B   
instance    profit  time    profit  time
x           10      0.5     39      0.9
y           20      0.1     12      1.2
z           13      0.7     14      0.6
```

I have tried using pivot and pivot_table with no success. Is there any way to achieve this result with pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.melt.html) to get`'profit'` and `'time'` in the same column, and then use a [`pivot table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) with multiple column levels

```
(df.melt(id_vars=['instance', 'algo'])
.pivot_table(index='instance', columns=['algo', 'variable'], values='value'))
#algo          A           B     
#variable profit time profit time
#instance                        
#x          10.0  0.5   39.0  0.9
#y          20.0  0.1   12.0  1.2
#z          13.0  0.7   14.0  0.6
```

Comment: I like this answer as well. +1

Answer (score 1):

`set_index` and `unstack`:

```
df.set_index(['instance', 'algo']).unstack().swaplevels(1, 0, axis=1)


         profit     time     
algo          A   B    A    B
instance                     
x            10  39  0.5  0.9
y            20  12  0.1  1.2
z            13  14  0.7  0.6
```

---

```
(df.set_index(['instance', 'algo'])
   .unstack()
   .swaplevel(1, 0, axis=1)
   .sort_index(axis=1))

algo          A           B     
         profit time profit time
instance                        
x            10  0.5     39  0.9
y            20  0.1     12  1.2
z            13  0.7     14  0.6
```

---

Another option is using `pivot` and `swaplevel`:

```
(df.pivot('instance', 'algo', ['profit', 'time'])
   .swaplevel(1, 0, axis=1)
   .sort_index(axis=1))

algo          A           B     
         profit time profit time
instance                        
x          10.0  0.5   39.0  0.9
y          20.0  0.1   12.0  1.2
z          13.0  0.7   14.0  0.6
```